# Is there a word or phrase to describe repeating the same word (maybe three times) for emphasis?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In spoken language, it seems to be a natural thing to repeat a word three times to emphasise the urgency, the importance and to acknowledge the situation.

For instance,

> come, come, come
>
> ok, ok, ok
>
> alright, alright, alright
>
> go, go, go
>
> yes, yes, yes

Is there a word or phrase to describe that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a form of literary rhetoric, the repetition of a word without any intervening words is called *epizeuxis*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis):

> In rhetoric, an **epizeuxis** is the repetition of a word or phrase in immediate succession, typically within the same sentence, for vehemence or emphasis. A closely related rhetorical device is diacope, which involves word repetition that is broken up by a single intervening word, or a small number of intervening words.
>
> As a rhetorical device, epizeuxis is utilized to create an emotional appeal, thereby inspiring and motivating the audience. However, epizeuxis can also be used for comic effect.

It includes several [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis#Examples) of the use of *epizeuxis*, including the following:

> "Never give in — never, never, never, never, in nothing great or small, large or petty, never give in except to convictions of honour and good sense. Never yield to force; never yield to the apparently overwhelming might of the enemy."
> —Winston Churchill
>
> “Isn’t it extraordinary that the Prime Minister of our country can’t even urge his Party to support his own position?! Yeah. Weak! Weak! Weak!”
> —Tony Blair

The number of repetitions is not specified. So, there is no word that specifically means *to repeat a word three times*.

---

In [another article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)) that lists other forms of repetition, Wikipedia says this about repetition in general:

> **Repetition** is the simple repeating of a word, within a short space of words (including in a poem), with no particular placement of the words to secure emphasis. It is a multilinguistic written or spoken device, frequently used in English and several other languages, such as Indian and Chinese, and so rarely termed a figure of speech.
>
> Its forms, many of which are listed below, have varying resonances to listing (forms of enumeration, such as "Firstly, Secondly, Thirdly and lastly..."), as a matter of trite logic often similar in effect.